# How to Detect and Draw Hough Transform Lines at a certain range of angles

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, edge-detection, hough-transform

I am trying to detect edges at a certain range of angles using Probabilistic Hough Transform. I am able to detect the lines but my code is not showing the lines at the angle ranges I want. I just need some help in the implementation process in Python.

```
def gtob(image):
       cdst = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
       cdstP = np.copy(cdst)
       return cdstP
    

x = segmentation(img)
canny = canny_with_threshold(x)
z = gtob(canny)
theta = np.pi / 180
linesP = cv2.HoughLinesP(canny, 1, theta, 50, None, 150, 10)

if linesP is not None:
    for i in range(0, len(linesP)):
        l = linesP[i][0]
        #p_h = cv2.line(z, (l[0], l[1]), (l[2], l[3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
        x1 = (l[0])
        y1 = (l[1])
        x2 = (l[2])
        y2 = (l[3])
        slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
        angle = math.atan(slope)
        if (angle > 95 and angle < 165):
            m =cv2.line(z, (l[0], l[1]), (l[2], l[3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow('ses',m)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Ignoring everything else, `math.atan` returns angles in radians, not degrees.

Answer (score 2):

You can find lines with `cv2.HoughLinesP` and then filter the results depending on angles.

1. As [beaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377097/beaker) noted in the comment `math.atan` returns angles in radians not degrees.
2. Also you may need to change your ranges to (-90, 90)

Example of an image:

[image]

Lines with depicted angles (blue lines is for angles within (-45, +45) range, red lines for other anlges):

[image]

Code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("lines.jpg")
canny = cv2.Canny(image, 150, 200)

theta = np.pi / 180
linesP = cv2.HoughLinesP(canny, rho=1, theta=theta, threshold=100, minLineLength=100, maxLineGap=100)

used_angles = []
if linesP is not None:
    for line in linesP:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
        slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
        angle = np.math.atan(slope) * 180. / np.pi

        # Skip duplicated angles just for visualization
        similar = sum([np.abs(used_angle - angle) < 2 for used_angle in used_angles])
        if similar:
            continue
        used_angles.append(angle)

        if -45 < angle < 45:
            cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, f'{angle:.2f}', (x1, y1), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        else:
            cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(image, f'{angle:.2f}', (x1, y1), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)


cv2.imshow("ses", image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your reply, I am only trying to detect/draw the lines which are between angles -45 and +45 degrees and discard the other lines. how to do that?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include code on how angles can be filtered.